# _TypeError (type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<Stations>')

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

Have recently installed Flutter `null safety` and having fixed most of the code I am having trouble with an API call.

It returns `_TypeError (type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<Stations>')`

I haven't found a SO answer that seems to line up with my issue/ code method.

This is the button click that calls the API from main.dart

```
void _anchoredMapMarkersButtonClicked() {
    _mapMarkerExample.showAnchoredMapMarkers();
  }
```

And this is the API call itself with error displaying at the bottom `} catch(Exception) {` line

```
 Future<Stations> fetchStations() async {
    var client = http.Client();
    var stations;
     
   Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);


    var lat = position.latitude;
    var long = position.longitude;
    
try{
    var response = await client.get(Uri.parse('https call'));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
   var jsonString = response.body;
   var jsonMap = json.decode(jsonString);
   
   stations = Stations.fromJson(jsonMap);
   //print(stations);
  }
} catch(Exception) {
  return stations;
}

  return stations;
}
```

Updated Code

```
Future<Stations> fetchStations() async {
    var client = http.Client();
    Stations? stations;
     
   Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
   print(position);


    var lat = position.latitude;
    var long = position.longitude;
    
try{
    var response = await client.get(Uri.parse('https://transit.hereapi.com/v8/stations?in=$lat,$long&return=transport&apiKey=uIioesb_EbnEXgPHlH0Z5e7gPGy9irpq2dRJcjuYPZY'));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
   var jsonString = response.body;
   var jsonMap = json.decode(jsonString);
   //print(jsonMap);
   inspect(jsonMap);
   
   stations = Stations.fromJson(jsonMap);
   //print(stations);
  }
} catch(Exception) {
  Future<Stations?> fetchStations()
}

  Future<Stations?> fetchStations()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you enable null safety, each type is divided into nullable and non-nullable type, as shown in the following picture, from dart official docs [Non-nullable and nullable types](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#non-nullable-and-nullable-types) [image]

So when you declare `var stations`, by default it have the value `dynamic`, which -in dart null safety- can be null, but the return of the function is of type `Future<Stations>`, in which the value of the future `Stations` can never be null (because it doesn't have the ? after the type),To solve this, you have to options:

#### First option,

declare your stations variable like this

```
Stations? stations; // you tell the compiler that this variable can hold null value
```

and then make the return of the function

```
Future<Stations?> fetchStations()
```

this way it's valid that you return null from the function.

#### Second option,

is declaring stations as non null like this

```
Stations stations; // this will give a compiler error
```

but now you'll have a compiler error that stations is a non null type and you didn't it assign it any value, you can either assign an initial value to it

```
Stations stations = Stations();
```

Or, use the `late` keyword,

```
late Stations stations; // tell the compiler that this is non null object that i'll assign a value to later
```

but notice that in the latter, you have to assign `stations` a value at some point, if you don't you'll get an exception.

if you chose the first option, the function should look like the following,

```
Future<Stations?> fetchStations() async {
    var client = http.Client();
    Stations? stations;
     
   Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);


    var lat = position.latitude;
    var long = position.longitude;
    
try{
    var response = await client.get(Uri.parse('https call'));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
   var jsonString = response.body;
   var jsonMap = json.decode(jsonString);
   
   stations = Stations.fromJson(jsonMap);
   //print(stations);
  }
} catch(e) {
  // you don't need to return stations, because you return it at the end of the function
  // return stations;
  print("Exception Happened: ${e.toString()}")
}
  // you can return a nullable object because the function return type is a nullable type
  return stations; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive response, I can now see where I went wrong. When implementing the first solution the fetchStations() section of the return type is red underlined and not functioning, any idea why this could be? One of the errors is ```Error: A non-null value must be returned since the return type 'Stations' doesn't allow null.```

Comment: You have to make the function return a nullable object, just add a `?` after `Stations`. `Future<Stations?>`.

Comment: I have added the version you posted with the ```?``` after ```Stations``` making it nullable, I still have the ```fetchStations()``` portion of the line red underlined with various suggested fixes such as ```Remove unused local variable``` and ```add ;```, which all do not solve the issue. Should I be including ```return``` before ```Future<Stations?> fetchStations() ```? It throws errors still. Thanks again

Comment: can update the question with that code please? i need to have a look at the code to answer you

Comment: I have updated code with the added updates suggested, ```fetchStations()``` is red underlined and not functioning on the first line and not on the bottom two either. Thank you

Comment: Issue on the top line ```Future<Stations> fetchStations() async {```, section ```fetchStations()``` is ```The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type is a potentially non-nullable type.
Try adding either a return or a throw statement at the end.```

Comment: i've added the code, kindly check it

Comment: Thanks for the update. Thats solves all visual errors, until I run it. I now receive the error ```Exception Happened: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'```  on the fetch. Could this be a problem with my Json model being adapted for null safety?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240766/discussion-between-michael-soliman-and-al246).